# Como puedo crear un Metodo Mostrar

Tags: java

> Cree un algoritmo que guarda un Array tipo Objeto y quiero crear 2 metodos, uno para crear un Estudiante Nuevo y otro para Mostrarlo.

Ya hice las clases:

- `Estudiante` (datos basicos)
- Crear(nuevo y el que me falta mostrar).

El problema es que puedo usar el metodo de Nuevo desde el Main, pero no se cómo hacer para hacer el de Mostrar.

```
class Crear {
public void Nuevo(int x){
    String nombre, apellido, curso;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    Estudiante estudiante[] = new Estudiante[x];
    for(int i=0;i<estudiante.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Nombre ");
        nombre = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Apellido ");
        apellido = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Curso ");
        curso = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("---------------");
        Estudiante nuevoEst = new Estudiante(nombre, apellido, curso);
        estudiante[i] = nuevoEst; 
    }  
}

public void Mostrar(*Arreglo estudiante del metodo anterior*){ 
    for(int i=0;i<estudiante.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Estudiante # "+(i+1));
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+estudiante[i].getNombre());
        System.out.println("Apellido: "+estudiante[i].getApellido());
        System.out.println("Curso: "+estudiante[i].getCurso());
    }
}
```

Main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Cuantos alumnos: ");
    int x = leer.nextInt();

    Crear nuevo = new Crear();
    nuevo.Nuevo(x);
    //llamada al metodo Mostrar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el valor del array estudiantes en el momento que termina la ejecución del método nuevo no se está guardando su valor, ya que el ámbito de esa variable es únicamente en el de ese método por lo que deberías de guardar el valor de esa variable como un atributo de la clase o retornarlo al finalizar el método.

```
public Estudiante[] Nuevo(int x){
String nombre, apellido, curso;
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
Estudiante estudiante[] = new Estudiante[x];
for(int i=0;i<estudiante.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Nombre ");
    nombre = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Apellido ");
    apellido = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Curso ");
    curso = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("---------------");
    Estudiante nuevoEst = new Estudiante(nombre, apellido, curso);
    estudiante[i] = nuevoEst; 
}
return estudiante;
```

}

Una posible solución podría ser esta, ten en cuenta que tienes que cambiar el tipo de retorno del método para poder retornar arrays de estudiantes, de esta forma para utilizarlo dentro del main deberás hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Cuantos alumnos: ");
int x = leer.nextInt();

Crear nuevo = new Crear();
Estudiante estudiante[] = nuevo.Nuevo(x);
nuevo.Mostrar(estudiante);
//llamada al metodo Mostrar
```

}

Deberías de tener en cuenta que el nombre de los métodos en Java comienza por minúscula y el de las clases por mayúscula, entre otras cosas. Puedes consultar la guía de estilo de Java en este enlace [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo primeramente para mejorar tu codigo, en la clase alumno podrias crear un metodo para poder "`LeerEstudiante()`"  y tambien para "`MostrarEstudiante()`" y en tu clase Crear simplemente crearias el metodo "`Nuevo(n)`" donde instancies un Estudiante tempooral n veces que vas ejecuntando el "`LeerEstudiante()`" vas agregando a tu array y de la misma forma, en el metodo para mostrar todos los Estudiantes desde la clase Crear ejecutas el metodo "`MostrarEstudiantes()`" la cantidad de estudiates agregados que seria n, saludos y respondeme para poder enviarte el codigo.
La clase CREAR seria asi, pero tendrias un error al momento de agregar estudaintes ya se serian todos null, por lo que te recomiendo que la clase Estudiante tenga su metodo de Leer sus datos y de Mostrar

```
public class Crear {
//ATributo
Estudiante estudiantes[];
int nroEstudiantes=0;
//Inicializar el array
public void Nuevo(int x){
    estudiantes = new Estudiante[x];
    nroEstudiantes+=x;
    //Instanciamos un alumno temporal que se ira agregando
    String nombre, apellido, curso;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        System.out.println("Nombre ");
        nombre = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Apellido ");
        apellido = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Curso ");
        curso = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("---------------");
        Estudiante nuevoEst = new Estudiante(nombre, apellido, curso);
        estudiantes[i] = nuevoEst; 
    }  
}
//Metodos
public void Mostrar(){ 
    for(int i=0;i<nroEstudiantes;i++){
        System.out.println("Estudiante # "+(i+1));
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+estudiantes[i].getNombre());
        System.out.println("Apellido: "+estudiantes[i].getApellido());
        System.out.println("Curso: "+estudiantes[i].getCurso());
    }
}
```

}